# generating of mipmaps using vkCmdBlitImage for cubemap textures

Tags: vulkan

what should be the parameters of VkImageBlit.dstOffsets and VkImageBlit.srcOffsets when we are doing dynamic generation of mipmaps? 
I am doing layer by layer and for each mipmap level but somewhere it is going wrong, mostly i think offsets. So i have data which has all the six faces with 0th mipmap level.

```
for(int j=0; j< bufferCopyRegions.size(); j++) {

    for (int32_t i = 1; i < mipLevels; i++)
    {

        VkImageBlit imageBlit{};

        // Source
        imageBlit.srcSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
        imageBlit.srcSubresource.layerCount = 1;
        imageBlit.srcSubresource.mipLevel = 0;

        imageBlit.srcOffsets[1].x = bitmapInfos[j].width;  
        imageBlit.srcOffsets[1].y = bitmapInfos[j].height;  
        imageBlit.srcOffsets[1].z = 1;

        // Destination
        imageBlit.dstSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
        imageBlit.dstSubresource.layerCount = 1;
        imageBlit.dstSubresource.mipLevel = i;


        imageBlit.dstOffsets[1].x = int32_t(bitmapInfos[j].width >> (i) == 0 ? 1 : int32_t(bitmapInfos[j].width >> (i )));
        imageBlit.dstOffsets[1].y = int32_t(bitmapInfos[j].height >> (i) == 0 ? 1 : int32_t(bitmapInfos[j].height >> (i)));
        imageBlit.dstOffsets[1].z = 1;

        VkImageMemoryBarrier imageMemoryBarrier = {};
        imageMemoryBarrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
        imageMemoryBarrier.pNext = NULL;
        imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
        imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = i;
        imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
        imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = j;
        imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;

        // change layout of current mip level to transfer dest
        setImageLayout(imageMemoryBarrier,
                       blitCmd,
                       image,
                       VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT,
                       VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED,
                       VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange,
                       VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
                       VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT);

        // Do blit operation from previous mip level
        vkCmdBlitImage(blitCmd, image, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL, image,
                VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, 1, &imageBlit, VK_FILTER_LINEAR);


        setImageLayout(imageMemoryBarrier, blitCmd, image, VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT,
                       VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,
                       VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL, imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange,
                       VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT,
                       VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Considering for how many this tends to be a surprise after it is pointed out, please automatically say you have validation layers enabled (and include warning or error reports if any in your Q)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see `baseArrayLayer` of the `imageBlit.srcSubresource` and `imageBlit.dstSubresource` set to `j`. Which is probably your immediate problem.

Also your barriers seem bad to me. Only the top mip needs to be synchronized with host. But even so `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT` should **not** be necessary, because there is an exception for `vkQueueSubmit` saying it does this kind of synchronization implicitly if host writes ended before it being called ([6.9. Host Write Ordering Guarantees](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-submission-host-writes) and reminded in the Note in [6.1.3. Access Types](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-access-types)).

Comment: There is no need to use host_stage here since the barrier is done implicitly when subșitting command buffer

Comment: @AntoineMorrier Right. Forgot about that rule. Merging. Thanks.